# How to get the ajax response in Ajax.Responders in prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to get the response of each Ajax call in below function

```
  Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: function() {

  },
  onComplete: function(transport) {

  },
  onSuccess: function(transport) {

  },

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onComplete: function(request, transport) { 
    console.log(request.transport.responseText) 
    console.log(transport.responseText) 
  } 
})
```

Comment: @Chirag please also see [`Ajax.Response`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Response/)